# How to do an update query using a specific record from another table in Access?

Tags: ms-access

I'm using Access 2010 and I want to know how to update a record from one table with the information from another table (but also, I want to specify which record from that other table I want to use). I have two tables (Products and Sales). What I need to do is that when I register a new sale on the Sales Form (specifying the units sold), I want to discount the units sold from the available units of that product in the Products table. I read that I need to use an Update Query, and do something like this:

```
Field: Available units
Table: Products
Update to: [Products].[Available units] - [Sales].[Sold units]

Field: Code
Table: Products
Update to: 
Criteria: [Insert code]
```

The two tables are related by the Code field, being Code the primary key field from the products table (the products are registered only once) and the primary key field from the sales table is a auto-numbered field called SaleNumber. There can be many sales for one product.

I hope you can help me, I can't find anything. I'm kind of new in Access.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using a form and want to write a bit of VBA, you can create a submit button that runs everything you need.  It could look something like this:

```
Private Sub Submit_Button_Click()

Dim myR as Recordset
Dim myR2 as Recordset
Dim strSQL as String

'Select the product from the table that contains the available products
strSQL = "SELECT * FROM Available_Units WHERE Products = '" & me.product_field & "'"

'Set each table accordingly
Set myR as CurrentDb.OpenRecordset(strSQL, dbOpenDyanset)
Set myR2 as CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("Sold_Units_Table", dbOpenDynaset)

'This will edit the existing amount you have in the first table
myR.Edit
myR![Product_Qty] = myR![Product_Qty] - me.qty_sold
myR.Update

'This will add a new record of the transaction in the second table
myR2.addnew
myR2![Product_Sold] = me.product_field
myR2![Product_Qty_Sold] = me.qty_sold
myR2.Update

Set myR = Nothing
Set myR2 = Nothing

End Sub
```

Hopefully this will help a bit if you wanted to go the VBA route.